# Observational evidences of the early universe other than CMB

Tags: cosmology, experimental-physics, astronomy, universe

CMB is a great experimental evidence that the universe was once in an hot themal phase  at early times. Supposing all the CMB observations failed for tecnical reason (for example the rocket shipping the plank satellite exploded) would we have other independent evidences of that hot and dense phase? What are those evidences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universe contains lots of deuterium, even though deuterium is destroyed, rather than made, inside stars.

To make deuterium, the universe must have been hot and dense enough to fuse protons, but then must have cooled and become less dense so that all the deuterium didn't end up forming helium.

The primordial abundances of deuterium and helium are simultaneously well-predicted by the temperature and density evolution implied by the big-bang model.